# Parameterizing managed bean instance as composite component attribute

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I've been searched how to parametrize the Managed Bean class, and until now nothing.

**What I'm doing?**

I have a JSF component that access some methods from my Bean, but this methods are already implemented by an abstract Class.

The name of the methods and attributes don't change, but now I'm copying and pasting, changing only the Bean name.

The first implementation is work, but I would like to improve with the second one.

**1- Component (Now):**

```xml
...
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="title"         type="java.lang.String"  required="true"/>
    <cc:attribute name="data"          type="java.util.List"    required="true"/>
    <cc:attribute name="columnModel"   type="java.util.List"    required="true"/>
    <cc:attribute name="newEntity"     type="java.lang.Object"  required="true"/>
    <cc:attribute name="crudState"     type="java.lang.Integer" required="true"/>
</cc:interface>
...
<cc:implementation>
    <p:dataTable var="entity" value="#{cc.attrs.data}" >
        <p:columns value="#{cc.attrs.columnModel}" 
            var="column" style="#{column.style}" 
            styleClass="#{column.styleClass}">
        ...
        </p:columns>
    </p:dataTable>
</cc:implementation>
...
```

**1- Implementations (Now):**

```xml
    ...
    <comp:crud 
        title="#{cfgUserBean.title}"
        data="#{cfgUserBean.data}"
        columnModel="#{cfgUserBean.coluuns}"
        newEntity="#{cfgUserBean.newEntity}"
        newEntity="#{cfgUserBean.crudState}"/>
    ...
    <comp:crud 
        title="#{cfgCityBean.title}"
        data="#{cfgCityBean.data}"
        columnModel="#{cfgCityBean.columns}"
        newEntity="#{cfgCityBean.newEntity}"
        crudState="#{cfgCityBean.curdState}"/>
```

**Desired:**

Pass the Bean Name as a Parameter

**2- Component (Desired):**

```xml
...
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="BEANNAME" type="java.lang.Object"  required="true"/>
</cc:interface>
...
<cc:implementation>
    <p:dataTable var="entity" value="#{cc.attrs.BEANNAME.data}" >
        <p:columns value="#{cc.attrs.BEANNAME.columnModel}" 
            var="column" style="#{column.style}" 
            styleClass="#{column.styleClass}">
        ...
        </p:columns>
    </p:dataTable>
</cc:implementation>
```

**2- Implementations (Desired):**

```xml
    ...
    <comp:crud BEANNAME="cfgUserBean" />
    ...
    <comp:crud BEANNAME="cfgCityBean" />
```

**Conclusion**

As you can see, If I could parametrize the Bean name, I would be able to simplify a lot the final coding.

Any one with any Idea what I could do?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helped by @BalusC to clarify my ideas, and I notice that the second implementation almost answered my question.

So, that what I did:

**Componet**

```
...
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="managedBean"  type="company.AbstractWebCrud" required="true"/>
</cc:interface>
...
<cc:implementation>
    <p:dataTable var="entity" value="#{cc.attrs.managedBean.data}" >
    ...
    </p:dataTable>
</cc:implementation>
...
```

**Implementation**

```
...
<comp:crud-lista 
    managedBean="#{cfgUserBean}"/>
...
```

**Conclusion**

Passing the abstract class as the parameter type, I was able to access all public methods from the class. Worked like a charm!

Thank you @BalusC for attention!! :-)